# resetting restartCount of pods with static names

Tags: kubernetes

For monitoring purposes, I want to rely on a pod's restartCount. However, I cannot seem to do that for certain apps, as restartCount is not reset even after rebooting the whole node the pod is scheduled to run on.

Usually, restarting a pod resets this, **unless the pod name of the restarted pod is the same** (e.g. true for etcd, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler and kube-apiserver).

For those cases, there is a [longrunning minor issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50375) as well as the idea to use `kubectl patch`.

To sum up the info there, `kubectl edit` will not allow to change anything in status. Unfortunately, neither does e.g.

```
kubectl -n kube-system patch pod kube-controller-manager-some.node.name --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/containerStatuses/0/restartCount", "value": 14}]'

The Pod "kube-controller-manager-some.node.name" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

So, I am checking if anyone has found a workaround?

Thanks!

Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be quite an old issue (2017). Take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54476).

I believe the solution to it was supposed to be [implementing unique UIDs for static pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/43420). This issue got reopened few days ago as [another github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87461) and hasn't been implemented to this day.

I have found a workaround for it. You need to change static pod manifest file e.g. by adding some random annotation to pod.

Let me know if it was helpful.